# Hamiltonian for electron hole

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, many-body, second-quantization

I found in lectures notes that the Hamiltonian containing the energy of a electron hole without any interaction is given by $$H = \sum_k d_k^{\dagger} d_k \left( \frac{\hbar k^2}{2m_V} - E_{0,V} \right)$$

and was now wondering if anybody here is familiar with this notation? Apparently, $d_k,d^{\dagger}_k$ are creation and annihilation operators of electron holes, but I am more confused about the energy term itself. Does anybody know what the terms in $\left( \frac{\hbar k^2}{2m_V} - E_{0,V} \right)$ actually correspond to? Any kind of clarification would be very valuable.

Comment: Which lectures notes?

Comment: @Qmechanic they are not available online, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k$ is the wave vector of the valence band that the hole resides.

$m_V$ is usually denoted as an effective mass of the hole. The effective mass is described in the band structure of the semiconductor.

$E_{0,v}$ is most likely a first-approximation of the electrostatic energy of the lattice. In the first approximation, it just shifts the allowed quantized energies of the holes, since the holes are repelled from the lattice but still bound by the electron field.

Note that the Hamiltonian this takes the form of

$$H = \sum_n a^\dagger_n a_n$$

which is the number operator of bosonic *or fermionic* particles, whose creation and annihilation operators have their specific commutation algebra.

Comment: Editted because I may have misled you by talking about bosons. The hole is a fermion and these creation and annilihation operators are fermions.